# SSRS Report Generate by using selected columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

[image]

How to do this report using SSRS?

Comment: What is the query that supports this report?

Comment: One way would be to return your data in SomeRowGroupID - FieldID - FieldOrder - FieldName - FieldValue fashion and then add a row group to the report based on "SomeRowGroupID" and then add a columnwise group based on "FieldID" ordered by "FieldOrder".

Comment: Are you saying you want your report to be a table that only shows the columns selected?

Comment: yes @Bostaevski . All the table columns should come in a drop down with checkbox and the report will generate based on selected columns from the drop down.

Comment: @WEI_DBA its SQL SERVER

Comment: I know, but what query generates the dataset for this report? Can you post the query?

Comment: If you are after something where the end user is able to dynamically build a report, SSRS cannot do this. You need to look at Power BI or data import into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done for simple tables.  May also work for complex groups but I haven't tested that.

Starting with this as a sample dataset:

```
SELECT
    v.Column1
,   v.Column2
,   v.Column3
,   v.Column4
FROM (VALUES
    (1,2,3,4)
,   (2,4,6,8)
,   (4,8,12,16)
) v (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4)
```

Here is the table in SSRS

[image]

Now add a new parameter to your report.  Make it a multi-value parameter.  Add a label/value pair for each column you want to be able to show/hide.

[image]

Finally, for each column, right-click the column and select **Column Visibility...**

Set to "Show or hide based on an expression"

Set the expression to this (replacing "Column1" with the name of the relevant column):

```
=IIF(Array.IndexOf(Parameters!ColumnChooser.Value, "Column1") > -1, FALSE, TRUE)
```

That setting the Hidden property to TRUE if the column is not checked in the multi-value drop down.

For example, I unchecked Column2 and Column3 in the dropdown list and ran the report:

[image]